# Player.sendMessage() Sends twice

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a **Bukkit plugin**, this plugin is an **account** plugin, and this **class** handles the events when the player is logged in. For some reason the **BlockPlaceEvent** stops the event from happening if the player isn't logged into his server account and sends him the message. Everything is fired correctly. But for some reason it sends him the message twice.

Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void OnPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent PQE) {
    // Case the PQE Entity to a player.
    Player Player = (Player) PQE.getPlayer();

    // Get the players UUID to open the file needed
    String UserUUID = Player.getUniqueId().toString();

    // Open the file and read it
    File Directory = new File("./plugins/ServerUtils/ServerAccounts/" + UserUUID + ".json");
    if(Directory.exists()) {
        try {
            JSONObject NewFinalResult = new JSONObject(this.readFile(Directory));
            NewFinalResult.getJSONObject("info").put("loggedin", false);
            this.overWriteToFile(Directory, NewFinalResult.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@EventHandler
public void OnPlayerChat(PlayerChatEvent PCE) {
    Player Player = (Player) PCE.getPlayer();
    String UserUUID = Player.getUniqueId().toString();
    File Directory = new File(Directories.ServerAccounts + "/" + UserUUID + ".json");
    JSONObject UserFileJSON = new JSONObject(this.readFile(Directory));
    if(UserFileJSON.getJSONObject("info").getBoolean("loggedin") == false) {
        PCE.setCancelled(true);
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be logged in to do this!");
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "To log in, simply type: " + ChatColor.BLUE + "\"/login <password>\"");
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void OnBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent BBE) {
    Player Player = (Player) BBE.getPlayer();
    String UserUUID = Player.getUniqueId().toString();
    File Directory = new File(Directories.ServerAccounts + "/" + UserUUID + ".json");
    JSONObject UserFileJSON = new JSONObject(this.readFile(Directory));
    if(UserFileJSON.getJSONObject("info").getBoolean("loggedin") == false) {
        BBE.setCancelled(true);
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be logged in to do this!");
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "To log in, simply type: " + ChatColor.BLUE + "\"/login <password>\"");
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void OnBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent BPE) {
    Player Player = (Player) BPE.getPlayer();
    String UserUUID = Player.getUniqueId().toString();
    File Directory = new File(Directories.ServerAccounts + "/" + UserUUID + ".json");
    JSONObject UserFileJSON = new JSONObject(this.readFile(Directory));
    if(UserFileJSON.getJSONObject("info").getBoolean("loggedin") == false) {
        BPE.setCancelled(true);
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be logged in to do this!");
        Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "To log in, simply type: " + ChatColor.BLUE + "\"/login <password>\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the same event twice? Or maybe you are getting 2 different events at the same time? You could change the message for each event a little so you can see which event it is sending a message for.

Comment: @DavidtenHove I removed the BlockBreakEvent, because I thought that would trigger when the BlockPlaceEvent Was cancelled, but removing didnt change anything. None of the other events do this.

Comment: @DavidtenHove I followed your advice, and made it say like "to place this block!" or "to chat!" So I knew which ones were firing, and the message "You must be logged in to place this block!" Popped up twice. So we know the same event is firing twice instead of other ones going off.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! For some reason, the message would send twice, So I added a number variable that made sure the times sent wasnt bigger than once, later, it set it back to 0.
Here is the code:

```
int TimesSent = 0;
@EventHandler
public void OnBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent BPE) {
    try {
        Player Player = (Player) BPE.getPlayer();
        String UserUUID = Player.getUniqueId().toString();
        File Directory = new File(Directories.ServerAccounts + "/" + UserUUID + ".json");
        JSONObject UserFileJSON = new JSONObject(this.readFile(Directory));
        if(UserFileJSON.getJSONObject("info").getBoolean("loggedin") == false) {
            BPE.setCancelled(true);
            if(TimesSent < 1) {
                Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be logged in to place this block!");
                Player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "To log in, simply type: " + ChatColor.BLUE + "\"/login <password>\"");
                TimesSent++;
            }
            else {
                TimesSent--;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception E) {
        if(E instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            //Ignore
        }
        else {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty nasty fix, if you ask me. Although the message is only being sent once, the code in that method is still triggering (creating `File`, reading and parsing; which are pretty process intensive activities). You should find the *actual* source of the problem and fix it, instead of using a cheap hack to ignore it. I also highly suggest NOT performing the file reading in a method thatll get called quite a few times. You should instead load in the player information *once*, keeping it stored in memory so yoy can easily access it without IO, then save to the file once you're done with the plugin

Comment: @VinceEmigh Ok, so previously load the IO when the plugin FIRST starts up, then call from it again later, Ill look at that. But I will have to do a long rewrite in the code, but it looks like it would be worth it. Also, Ill rename the TimesSent to TimesTriggered and put it around the whole thing, so not just the message is duplicated, I've been trying to fix the error without a if statement as listed above though.

Comment: Also, I think I found a fix, a real one. The core of the problem seems to be that the onEnable() in the main file (The thing that starts everything up) Is creating MULTIPLE listeners in one class.

Comment: That sounds very possible; maybe your listener isn't firing twice, rather than 2 listeners firing once. And yes, load in all the information when your plugin starts. There are only a few cases where you'd wanna perform IO every time, such as if the file is too large to keep in memory (which for this situation, I doubt it is)

Comment: @VinceEmigh The fix I thought it was didnt work. I dont know why its firing twice? NONE of the other events fire twice.

Comment: If you edited your code into your question, I could help you further

Comment: @VinceEmigh Ok, could you move this discussion to chat?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Oddly enough, I found out that the event fires once if the event ISNT Cancelled. Im starting this is a bug.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to chat (I suggest going around and editing a few things til you're at 20 rep). And I'm not sure what you mean by "it fires even if it isn't canceled"; you can only cancel it from within the handler method, yeah? (I don't use bukkit personally; my friends do and I help them out with their problems)

Comment: @VinceEmigh What I mean by that, is that when I removed the snippet  "BPE.setCancelled(true);" The event didnt fire twice, which is why I think its a bug, as none of the other events do this.

Comment: been there, done that @ registering same Listener multiple times